# Height and weight attributes being ignored by css

Tags: html, css

We just updates [our sites](http://defilmblog.be/) design, but we just can't figure out why CSS is ignoring height and width?

For instance, the YouTube embedded videos don't stay at 625x352

```
<iframe width="625" height="352" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jPcfAqIyuI4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the images with an original width of 155px and height of 250px don't transform to 155x180 as specified in the html.

```
<a href="http://my.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://thumbnail.jpg"  width="155" height="180" /></a>
```

Anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please add the significant code to your question.

Comment: We need code. Have you tried with `!important` in your css height and width values?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: First time posting, sorry. You want me to post the entire css code?

Answer (score 1):

for player remove width 100%

```
iframe {
  /* width: 100%; */
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

or you can add inline css **"width: initial;"** to iframe if you can not play with the stylesheet

```
<iframe width="625" height="352" width: initial;"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Tried the code in css, but not working. The YouTube video gets larger when the screen get bigger.

Comment: @JulieVanOlmen here is the screen shot http://res.cloudinary.com/madam-firsat/image/upload/v1435589421/29.6_zdf6vl.jpg

Comment: I added          iframe{min-width:0; max-width: 100%; } But the tricky thing is, I cannot delete the width:100% cause this css has been set by the bloghost. I can however overwrite the css.

Comment: So to solve this, how do I overwrite the width:100%  - I cannot put iframe{width:625px} cause i do have post with two youtube video's of 312 next to each other.

Comment: @JulieVanOlmen I Updated the answer for that case

Answer (score 1):

Hurray !! I found a solution to my problem.

instead of

> width="625px" height="352px"

I rewrote the style

> style="width:625px;height:352px;"

And it worked!